# Does React use requestAnimationFrame? If so, how does it use it?

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe, reactjs

I found 2 sources where it kind of says that React is using `requestAnimationFrame`
On this [blog post about Om](http://swannodette.github.io/2013/12/17/the-future-of-javascript-mvcs/), a ClojureScript framework on top of React.
Also on [the comments of this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21031832/82609).

I'm not sure it's part of React or if people are using it with React.

Can someone tell me what how `requestAnimationFrame` is used in React if it is? Or how it can be used with React and why I would choose to use it with React?

Comment: Do you need a motivation to use React?

Comment: @Pavlo no I'm already using it and try to understand it better or at least be able to use it correctly.

Comment: A quick search on github finds no (relevant) references: https://github.com/facebook/react/search?q=requestanimationframe&ref=cmdform There are more references to `setTimeout` and `setInterval`.

Comment: Pete Hunt talked about `requestAnimationFrame` in an interview in August 2013. The recording and transcript are available: http://javascriptjabber.com/073-jsj-react-with-pete-hunt-and-jordan-walke/

Comment: It is used to check for changes in the virtual DOM and update the DOM when necessary. This question isn't really suitable for SO. I would recommend to ask this question on Quora instead.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

React doesn't currently use `requestAnimationFrame` to do DOM updates (as we call it, the "batching strategy"). The batching strategy is injectible though so it's possible to use something else. Om makes use of that possibility and uses `requestAnimationFrame` to batch DOM updates.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain how this batching strategy is injectible?

Comment: Does this still hold true for React 18 in concurrent mode?

Comment: There's a question about using requestAnimationFrame here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24859412/batch-on-animation-frame