# Batch on animation frame

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why [doesn't reactjs batch on animation frame strategy by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21352587/does-react-use-requestanimationframe-if-so-how-does-it-use-it)?

Comment: Why should React batch using requestAnimationFrame by default?

Comment: I would guess because that would batch (reduce diff counts) as many operations as possible while still giving full framerate.

Comment: Note sure if that would give a performance increase. However, if not, I would like to understand why?

Answer (score 0):

There's a repo that will do that for you [react-raf-batching](https://github.com/petehunt/react-raf-batching).

In the Readme, Pete Hunt claims that using requestAnimationFrame makes things harder to test.

> A batching strategy for React that's more like a game. This may make your apps more performant but harder to test.