# id undefined in onChange event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker

Using react [datepicker](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker), I am trying to get the id of the clicked component

```
<DatePicker
id={cellData.column}
selected={DatePickerDate}
onChange={this.onDateRangePickerChange}
className='form-control'
                    />
```

In my click handler the event being passed is a moment date object, so `event.currentTarget` is undefined.

```
onDateRangePickerChange: function(event, picker){

        var localRowDataStack = _.cloneDeep(this.state.rowDataStack);
        localRowDataStack[event.currentTarget.id] = picker.startDate.format(appConfig.getKey('dateFormat'));
        this.setState({
            rowDataStack: localRowDataStack,
            isOmitReRender: false
        });

},
```

How can I get the id of the clicked datepicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `id` as first argument to `onDateRangePickerChange` with `.bind`, and thus avoid add `id` as `DatePicker` attribute

```
onDateRangePickerChange: function (column, date) {
  console.log(column, date);
},

<DatePicker
  selected={ DatePickerDate }
  onChange={ this.onDateRangePickerChange.bind(this, cellData.column) }
  className="form-control"
/>;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can as well extend onDateRangePickerChange to accept id and just pas it there like this:

```
<DatePicker
    id={cellData.column}
    selected={DatePickerDate}
    onChange={(e, p) => this.onDateRangePickerChange(e, p, cellData.column)}
    className='form-control'/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how do i do that with es5?

Comment: @Alexander provided you this sample in es5

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing this way:

```
onDateRangePickerChange: function(event){

        var id = event.target.id;  // ID from the element
        var localRowDataStack = _.cloneDeep(this.state.rowDataStack);
        localRowDataStack[id] = picker.startDate.format(appConfig.getKey('dateFormat'));
        this.setState({
            rowDataStack: localRowDataStack,
            isOmitReRender: false
        });
},
```

You could see more examples/responses here: [React.js: Identifying different inputs with one onChange handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21029999/react-js-identifying-different-inputs-with-one-onchange-handler)

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply, I still get the undefined id, as event is a moment date.