# Submitting big forms with react.js

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, form-submit

It's a pain to work with react.js when it comes to form. I was from angular, because of 2 ways binding things are great, it's fast to integrate stuff. But when in react I admit I'm lost.

Says it's a user profile, I got this data from API

```
var profile = {
    name:"Gaila",
    age:22,
    skills: [{id:1,name:"react"},{id:1,name:"angular"}],
    club: [{id:1,name:"dancing"},{id:1,name:"hiking"}],
    description: "some long string"
};
```

on the UI I have `text input`, `textarea`, `checkbox` and `select`.

How would I handle it when user clicked to save? Do I have to bind every single input elements with onChange? like handleNameChange, handleAgeChange, handleSkillsChange.. omg it's ridiculous.

So ref came into my mind, easy, just do `ref="name"` and I can get it by `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.name).value`, but wait, it doesn't work on `<select>`, it's bad sometime I use ref, sometime I go with handle function.

Guys, I seriously, really need help!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Why do you need to bind change functions if all you care about is submit? Are you trying to submit every time a form value changes?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21029999/react-js-identifying-different-inputs-with-one-onchange-handler

Comment: If you don't want to bind an event on every form element (You could reuse the same function remember so it's not that ridiculous) you could use Redux form.

Comment: @spirift can you show me an example? says u have 20 diff input elements

Comment: As @spirift said, You can use redux-form to manage all your forms state inside redux-store. You can start with these [examples](https://redux-form.com/6.5.0/examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of reusing an event handler and picking up the differences from the event. See it in action at [codepen](http://codepen.io/DriftDesign/pen/dvpZxM?editors=1111).

```
const FormFunc = () => {

  const changeHandler = (e) => {
    console.log(`e.target.name, name: `, e.target.name, e.target.value)
  }
  return (
    <form>
      <input onChange={changeHandler} type='text' name='firstName' />
      <input onChange={changeHandler} type='text' name='surname' />
      <input onChange={changeHandler} type='phone' name='phone' />
      <input onChange={changeHandler} type='email' name='email' />
    </form>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to extract form values, you can use form-serialize - it's available as a package through npm.

In your component, add a submit event to your form:

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
```

Your handler extracts the form like so:

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  const values = serializeForm(event.target, { hash: true })
  console.log(values)
}
```

Comment: can I have the link for the package? I'm not using jquery.

Comment: @GialaJefferson 2s on Google: https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-serialize

Comment: @DaveNewton is that for jquery?

Comment: @GialaJefferson jQuery? I don't understand.