# How to display EditText details below Labels in React js?

Tags: reactjs

Im try to display what user input below edit text but its not working all text fields link together

How can I make it work I need to display what user enter in below Label

```
class ComposedTextField extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: '',
    title: '',
    email: '',
    experience: ''
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ 
          name: event.target.value, 
          title: event.target.value,
          email: event.target.value,
          experience: event.target.value
        });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className={classes.container}>
        <Typography variant="headline">Header Info</Typography>
        <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
          <InputLabel htmlFor="name-simple">Name</InputLabel>
          <Input id="name-simple" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          <p>{this.state.name}</p>
        </FormControl>
        <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
          <InputLabel htmlFor="title-simple">Title</InputLabel>
          <Input id="title-simple" value={this.state.title} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          <p>{this.state.title}</p>
        </FormControl>
        <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
          <InputLabel htmlFor="email-simple">Email</InputLabel>
          <Input id="email-simple" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChange}/> 
          <p>{this.state.email}</p>
        </FormControl>
        <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
          <InputLabel htmlFor="experience-simple">Experience</InputLabel>
          <Input id="experience-simple" value={this.state.experience} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          <p>{this.state.experience}</p>
        </FormControl>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**How can I make this work please help me Im newbie**

Comment: There are many labels. As every FormControl section has one label. which one would you like to edit?

Comment: now if I change one edit text all labels getting changed. if i change name it should display in name label something like that

Comment: do I need to use separate handles for text fields

Comment: Can you check my answer below

Comment: check this example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lqh7pn

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21029999/react-js-identifying-different-inputs-with-one-onchange-handler ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `handleChange` method to this

```
 handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]:event.target.value });
  };
```

And decorate your input text elements with name attribute i.e.

```
<Input name="name" id="name-simple" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange}/>

<Input name="email" id="email-simple" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
```

Similarly you can do it for rest of the elements.

Now when you input something in the textboxes it will be set in state with current target's name and value

Answer (score 0):

Use your handle change method like as follows. This will fix yours

```
handleChange = event => {
  const { name, value } = event.target
  this.setState({ [name]: value });
};
```